# The PII section in the mod dashboard should state which PII exactly it contains

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools, pii

There is a section in the moderator dashboard on user profiles that is called "Personally Identifiable Information (PII)". If you click on it, you see a whole bunch of information that is considered PII.

This section explicitly warns that the access is logged, but what it doesn't tell you is what information exactly you're actually requesting there. Of course you'll see this after you request the PII, but I think this should also be explicitly mentioned before you confirm that you actually want to look at this.

Moderators generally don't access PII without a reason, this particular feature makes sure that you have to confirm that you access PII, but it makes it possible to request more information than you actually wanted. Especially new moderators, or moderators that haven't had much need to use these tools might not know which information they're requesting here.

Listing the information contained there before you click through would also help to emphasize that you're about to request the most sensitive PII that is available to moderators.

Comment: That bit's always felt a bit odd I can pull in a good chunk of that information from other sources  on the same page - I can see emails and ip addresses without clicking on that panel, and most of the other information there isn't something I've really needed so far.

Comment: If memory serves, that page started as a tool for those of us handling support emails (merges and such), where there was a whole bunch of information we needed for pretty much every request, and clicking through a half-dozen "show" links was getting real tedious... Probably not as useful a tool for most moderators.