# Can moderators view my registered email address?

Tags: discussion, pii

Can a moderator (or ex-moderator) view the registered email address if :

- I am a member of the particular SE site of which the moderator is moderating?
- I am not a member of the particular SE site of which the moderator is moderating?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295829/the-pii-section-in-the-mod-dashboard-should-state-which-pii-exactly-it-contains

Comment: probably answers your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/who-can-see-what-in-my-profile

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341309/restrict-moderator-tools-that-allow-mass-dumping-of-user-emails?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How does [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637/280335) not answer your question? `Things visible to ♦ moderators (of the site where your profile belongs to) only: email*` and `*mods have to click a link to see this information, the act of which is also logged.`. If it doesn't, explain why it doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only the active moderators **can** view your email address. You must be a member of a particular SE site for its moderators to be able to see it.

The former (ex) moderators, and the moderators of other SE communities, **have no access** to your PII, including your email address.

This question has a big overlap with [Who can see what in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149636/383809) and [Exactly which users PII do moderators have access to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341341/383809); however, I think it addresses a couple of details that are not mentioned there.